# I can't copy SpreadSheet data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to copy data from a specific column and put it in the correct months, but the error always appears:

> "The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 5."

Code:

```
    function reDatas() {

      var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Register');   
      var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Jan'); 

      sheet2.getRange("D6:D10").setValues([[
        sheet1.getRange('A4').getValue(),
        sheet1.getRange('B4').getValue(),
        sheet1.getRange('C4').getValue(),
        sheet1.getRange('D4').getValue(),
        sheet1.getRange('E4').getValue()]])
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

sheet2.getRange("D6:D10").setValues ser this range to contain the cells you want to bring across like A1:E10?

Comment: I need to copy the data D6:D10 ("sheet1") to A4:E4 ("sheet2").
And as I copy it, it adds lines in "sheet2".

Answer (score 0):

You just have to convert you array which represent 1 line with 5 columns, in an array of 5 lines and 1 column.

```
function reDatas() {

  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Register');   
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Jan'); 

  sheet2.getRange("D6:D10").setValues([[
    sheet1.getRange('A4').getValue()],[
    sheet1.getRange('B4').getValue()],[
    sheet1.getRange('C4').getValue()],[
    sheet1.getRange('D4').getValue()],[
    sheet1.getRange('E4').getValue()]])
}
```

Stéphane

Comment: Thank you, Stephany. But I couldn't understand your answer.

Comment: You array was [[1,2,3,4,5]] so it is an array of 1 line 5 columns. Range D6 to D10 is a range of 5 lines if 1 column so it is [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]].

Comment: I was able to do it, but copying creates blank cells with no values.

Comment: On your print screen A4 B4 etc... looks to be empty so seems to be normal to copy blank data.